# SQL syntax error 1064 when trying to create a foreign key constraint in a create table query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create two tables with the following query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE person (
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id),
    person_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
)
ENGINE InnoDB CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
COMMENT "A list of people.";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logon;
CREATE TABLE logon (
    PRIMARY KEY (logon_id),
    logon_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    person_id INT NOT NULL,
              UNIQUE INDEX person_id (person_id),
              CONSTRAINT fk_logon_has_person
              FOREIGN KEY person_id REFERENCES person (person_id)
              ON UPDATE CASCADE
              ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    passwd    CHAR(60) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE InnoDB CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
COMMENT "Available logins for people.";
```

Running this query on HeidiSQL gives me this error:

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES person (person_id)
              ON UPDATE CASCADE
              ON' at line 7 */
```

I removed the foreign key constraint part completely and the query executes just fine.
Then I manually added the foreign key in HeidiSQL, which produced this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `logon` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_logon_has_person` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `playground`.`person` (`person_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

I tried to replace my create table query's constraint with its syntax (from ADD onwards, with the `s), but the error still appears.
I also tried removing the ON UPDATE/DELETE parts, and changing the logon table's person_id column name to something else so that it's not ambiguous with the person table's column, but no luck.
I've looked at [MariaDB's documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/#syntax) and the syntax looks correct to me. Now I have no idea why this wouldn't work.
Any ideas?

I'm using MariaDB v10.4.12 and HeidiSQL v11.0.0.5919.

Comment: in your `CREATE TABLE` statement put parantheses around the column(s): `FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES`

Comment: Okay now I feel very sheepish :D thank you! @fancyPants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by [fancyPants in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655765/sql-syntax-error-1064-when-trying-to-create-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-a-create/63656014#comment112564228_63655765):

> in your `CREATE TABLE` statement put parantheses around the column(s): `FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES`

Comment: I couldn't seem to able to mark fancyPant's comment as the answer, so I did as instructed [in this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1558/480242). @forpas

Comment: That link is correct: *you could always post an answer yourself that quotes the comment and mark it accepted*. But this: "Answered by fancyPants in the comments." is not an answer. Anyway the post is already edited by a moderator and now you can accept it to indicate that the problem is solved.